# Facebook Login and OpenID Connect

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Can someone confirm whether Facebook Login API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) is based on OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/connect/) specification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it isn't at the moment. Uses OAuth2 (also used by OIDC)

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to change that?

Answer (score 2):

This page

> https://developers.google.com/identity/

states that the "Google Sign-In" secure authentication system "gives you ... federated sign-in with ... Facebook".

[Google Sign-In is based on OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect).

I am not sure if the actually answers your question in the affirmative because the rest of the page only talks about signing in with Google.

Comment: If Google uses OpenId Connect why are there client libraries specifically for Google login instead of just using OpenIdConnect clients? (e.g. ``Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`?)

Comment: @Dai I can tell for sure that Google works with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` as I just implemented it - there might be multiple reasons for a seperate provider in the framework. It might be ease of use with predefined endpoints, or just to be equal with a facebook-provider. Or maybe there is something special about it I did not discover yet. Requested Claims get passed through successfully.